# rotate content pulled from a database and put in a table

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

I have an ASP website with an Access database on the back end. I'm trying to make it where one of my cells in the table on my website will rotate data from the database, say every 10 seconds or so. If I can use just ASP, that would be nice, but I'm open for most solutions.

Comment: Can you define "rotate data" for us please?

Comment: Must rotate without page reload?

Comment: I have pictures and text to go with the pictures that I want to rotate on the top of my webpage. And yes, I'd like not to have to refresh the entire page.